# Slim showing Application error when trying to call function

Tags: php, api, slim

When i am trying to call a function in slim it is showing application error, i am not able to find out the actual error

```
if(is_a_valid_route_user_action($this->from_user['action_id']))

     {
        return get_action_id_from_route_user_action($this->from_user['action_id']);

        }
```

get_action_id_from_route_user_action is the function which am trying to call

```
if(!function_exists('get_action_id_from_route_user_action'))
{
    function get_action_id_from_route_user_action($organization_id,$route_user_action_id)
    {

        $db = org_db_connection($organization_id);

        $get_previous_level_sql = "SELECT action_id from route_user_actions where id=".$route_user_action_id;

        $get_previous_level_object = mysqli_query($db, $get_previous_level_sql);

        if ($get_previous_level_object->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($get_previous_level= mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_previous_level_object))
            {
                $action_id = (int)$get_previous_level['action_id'];
                return $action_id;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does slim write a log file somewhere? If not, can you enable slim to write a log file? Are there entries in the web server's log files?

Comment: check your php `error_log`

Answer (score 1):

I enabled the error reporting, and it worked